# What is the eqivalent of VDB in PostgreSql?

Tags: postgresql

In sqLite the query is parsed,planned and while execution is done the code is converted to vdbe and then to assembly.
What is the equivalent is PostgreSql?

Comment: Please add some explanation. What does "VDB" stand for and quote a source if possible. Also be more specific. The equivalent in Postgres for what exactly?

Answer (score 2):

Why do you assume there is an equivalent? In pg the plan is passed to the executor but there is no virtual machine. Please refer to [overview of PostgreSQL internals](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/overview.html) in the manual.

Answer (score 0):

From the [SQLite manual](https://www.sqlite.org/vdbe.html):

> The [EXPLAIN] keyword will cause sqlite to print the VDBE program
>   rather than execute it.

I'm not a SQLite guru, but it looks like VDE stands for execution plan in PostgreSQL. Just use [EXPLAIN](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-explain.html) and/or EXPLAIN ANALYZE and see what the results are.

For more information, just check the manual on the [internals](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/internals.html).